# MongoDB $type check on a field inside $cond

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB and my requirement is to convert a string date to date. But that particular field is sometimes in date format sometimes in string format.

Effectively, If the date is in string format I want to convert it to date else leave as it is.

Sample data:

> paymentDate:2021-11-19T05:36:32.596+00:00

> paymentDate:'2021-11-19T05:36:32.596+00:00'

My attempt is

```
{
  convertedDate: {
    $cond: {
      if:
        {'$eq': [{$type:"$paymentDate"},9]}, 
      then:"$newField",
      else:{
        $dateFromString: {
           dateString: '$paymentDate'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost to the answer. Specify the compare value in `$type` as "date".

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  convertedDate: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        "$eq": [
          {
            $type: "$paymentDate"
          },
          "date"
        ]
      },
      then: "$paymentDate",
      else: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$paymentDate"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_dEXasNkCL6)

---

### References

[Available type | `$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types)

Comment: Hi @Julien, I rollback your edit as my answer is for query but not update. Anyway thanks for the efforts.

Comment: oh, right, sorry

Comment: Post Owner may take note that `$dateFromString` can be replaced with `{ '$toDate': '$paymentDate' }` as mentioned by @ray.

Comment: @YongShun Could you please tell why 9 didn't work?

Comment: Because 9 is not a valid type, check out the reference link I shared to you for list of types in MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2+, you may simply use `$toDate` to convert your field in an [update with aggregation pipeline operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "paymentDate": {
        "$toDate": "$paymentDate"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GMhRMAwDuVa) for your reference.